# Render Json data using componentWillmount React.Js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm pretty new in React and I'm trying to render data from a Json file, I've read a little bit about componentWillmount and componentDidmount but I have no idea of how to use it, so I'm pretty lost about what to do and where.

The call to Json is OK, I get the data but I doesn't know how to render it in my app...

I want to render the data in **ProductosDestacados** component and I'm showing the output of the data in **console.log(getWebServiceResponse(productsIdsJoin, 96));** so I know that the call function it's OK

This is my code (sorry, I had to hide part of it)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

// SETTINGS PARA CARRUSEL DE PRODUCTOS
var settings = {
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  initialSlide: 0,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        initialSlide: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
};
// END

// THIS IS THE CALL TO JSON
/**
 *
 * @param {*} productsIds List of products
 * @param {*} storeId the store ID
 */
var productsIds = ['3552357','2635968BC','3181464'];
var productsIdsJoin = productsIds.join('-');

const getProductDetailAPI = (productsIdsJoin, storeId) => ({
  method: 'GET',
  baseURL: `https://sample.data/json{ "productId" : "${productsIdsJoin}","storeId":"${storeId}"}`,
  auth: {
    username: 'XXXXXXXX',
    password: 'XXXXXXXX',
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: {},
});

const getWebServiceResponse = (currentList, storeId) => (
  axios(getProductDetailAPI(currentList, storeId))
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(newData => {
      newData.productDetailsJson.map(detail => {
        console.log(detail.productId);
      })
    })
    .catch(e => e)
);

console.log(getWebServiceResponse(productsIdsJoin, 96));

//END OF CALL

const ContenidoUnoTitulo = (props) => {
  return (
    <h1 id="titulo">
      {props.tituloUno}

    </h1>
  );
}

const ContenidoUno = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="contentBox outerBox-first" >
      <a href={props.link}><img src={props.imagen} alt="bloque 01" className="img-wrap" /></a>
      <h3>{props.categoria}</h3>
      <img src={props.icono} className="iconic" alt="producto" />
      <span>{props.descripcion}</span>
      <strong>${props.normal}</strong>
      <small>Antes: ${props.antes}</small>
      <div className="containerBotonRow">
        <a href={props.link}><button className="botonRow">¡Lo quiero!</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const ContenidoDosTitulo = (props) => {
  return (
    <h2 id="titulo" className="marginTop-6">
      {props.tituloDos}
    </h2>
  );
}

const ContenidoDos = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="contentBoxTwoMain outerBox-second">
      <a href={props.link}><img src={props.imagen} alt="bloque 01" className="img-wrap" /></a>
      <h3>{props.categoria}</h3>
      <img src={props.icono} className="iconic" alt="producto" />
      <span>{props.descripcion}</span>
      <strong>${props.normal}</strong>
      <small>Antes: ${props.antes}</small>
      <div className="containerBotonRow">
        <a href={props.link}><button className="botonRow">¡Lo quiero!</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const ContenidoDosRow = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="contentBoxTwoRow outerBox-second" >
      <a href={props.ancla}>
        <img src={props.imagen} alt="bloque 01" className="img-wrap" />
      </a>
      <h3>{props.categoria}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}


const BotonesLinkUno = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="btnPad" >
      <a href={props.boton}>
        <button className="botonRow">Todo Categoría</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

const ContenidoTresTitulo = (props) => {
  return (
    <h2 id="titulo" className="marginTop-6">
      {props.tituloTres}
    </h2>
  );
}

const ContenidoTres = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="contentBoxTwoMain outerBox-second" >
      <a href={props.link}><img src={props.imagen} alt="bloque 01" className="img-wrap" /></a>
      <h3>{props.categoria}</h3>
      <img src={props.icono} className="iconic" alt="producto" />
      <span>{props.descripcion}</span>
      <strong>${props.normal}</strong>
      <small>Antes: ${props.antes}</small>
      <div className="containerBotonRow">
        <a href={props.link}><button className="botonRow">¡Lo quiero!</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const ContenidoTresRow = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="contentBoxTwoRow outerBox-second" >
      <a href={props.ancla}>
        <img src={props.imagen} alt="bloque 01" className="img-wrap" />
      </a>
      <h3>{props.categoria}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}


const BotonesLinkDos = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="btnPad" >
      <a href={props.boton}>
        <button className="botonRow">Todo Categoría</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

const ContenidoCuatroTitulo = (props) => {
  return (
    <h2 id="titulo" className="marginTop-6">
      {props.tituloCuatro}
    </h2>
  );
}

const ContenidoCuatroBloques = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="contentBox outerBox-first">
        <a href={props.bloquesContentLink}><div className="boxInner"></div></a>
        <img src={props.bloquesContentImg} className="img-wrap" alt="Imagen" />
        <img src={props.bloquesContentIcono} className="iconicMid" alt="Imagen" />
        <a href={props.bloquesContentLink}>
          <h4>{props.bloquesContentTexto}</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const ContenidoCincoTitulo = (props) => {
  return (
    <h2 id="titulo" className="marginTop-6">
      {props.tituloCinco}
    </h2>
  );
}

const ProductosDestacados = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="contentBox outerBox-third" >
      <a href={props.link}>
      <div className="boxInfoSku">
        <img src={props.imagen} alt="bloque 01" className="img-wrap" />
        <br />
        <span>{props.descripcion}</span><br />
        <img src={props.icono} alt="producto" className="iconic" />
        <strong>${props.normal}</strong>
        <small>${props.antes}</small><br />
        <a href={props.link}><button className="botonRow" style={{ marginTop: '5px' }}>¡Lo quiero!</button></a>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

const ContenidoSeisTitulo = (props) => {
  return (
    <h2 id="titulo" className="marginTop-6">
      {props.tituloSeis}
    </h2>
  );
}

const Inspiracion = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="outerBox-inspiration anclaInspiracion">
      <div className={props.margen}>
        <a href={props.link}>
          <img src={props.banner} alt={props.descripcion} className="showFalseMobile" />
          <img src={props.bannerMob} alt={props.descripcion} className="showTrue" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <a href={props.link}>
        <div className={props.boxdisplay}>
          <h4>{props.title[0]}<strong>{props.title[1]}</strong></h4>
          <a href={props.link}><button className="botonRow">{props.boton}</button></a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

const ContenidoSieteTitulo = (props) => {
  return (
    <h2 id="titulo" className="marginTop-6">
      {props.tituloSiete}
    </h2>
  );
}

const ThirdContent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="contentBoxBlog">
          <div>
            <div className="topicoContent">
              <small>{props.topic}</small>
            </div>
            <a href={props.link}><img src={props.banner} alt={props.title} className="img-wrap" /></a>
            <strong>{props.title}</strong>
            <p>{props.preview.split(' ').slice(0, 15).join(' ') + '...'}</p>
            <a href={props.link}>Seguir leyendo...</a>
            <div className="infoEntradaBlog">
              <span>{props.date}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



class App extends Component {

  state = {
    titulos: [
      {
        tituloUno: 'Estas a un paso de enamorarte de estos productos',
        tituloDos: 'Muebles para crear espacios confortable',
        tituloTres: 'Decoración para que tus espacios sean únicos',
        tituloCuatro: '¿Buscas las mejores oportunidades? encuentra los mejores precios para ti',
        tituloCinco: '¡A todo el mundo le encantan! Productos destacados',
        tituloSeis: 'Inspírate con nuestro LookBook de la semana',
        tituloSiete: '¿Tiempo para lectura? Tendecias de diseño y deco en el blog Homy',
        key: 'mainTitles'
      }

    ],

    botonesLink: [
      {
        botonUno: 'http://youtube.com',
        botonDos: 'http://amazon.com',
        key: 'mainButtons'
      }
    ],

    contenidosUno: [
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/570x250',
        categoria: 'Categoria 01',
        linkCat: 'https://www.myapp.cl/myapp-homy/category/cat570061/accesorios-cocina',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/30/000000/FFFFFF',
        descripcion: 'Descripción de producto',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU01'
      },
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/570x250',
        categoria: 'Categoria 02',
        linkCat: 'https://www.myapp.cl/myapp-homy/category/cat570061/accesorios-cocina',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/30/000000/FFFFFF',
        descripcion: 'Descripción de producto',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU02'
      },
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/570x250',
        categoria: 'Categoria 03',
        linkCat: 'https://www.myapp.cl/myapp-homy/category/cat570061/accesorios-cocina',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/30/000000/FFFFFF',
        descripcion: 'Descripción de producto',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU03'
      },
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/570x250',
        categoria: 'Categoria 04',
        linkCat: 'https://www.myapp.cl/myapp-homy/category/cat570061/accesorios-cocina',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/30/000000/FFFFFF',
        descripcion: 'Descripción de producto',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU04'
      }
    ],

    contenidosDos: [
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/670x551',
        categoria: 'Categoria 01',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/30/000000/FFFFFF',
        descripcion: 'Descripción de producto',
        linkSku: 'https://www.myapp.cl/myapp-homy/product/332771X',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU05'
      }
    ],

    contenidosDosRow: [
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/470x249',
        categoria: 'Categoria 02',
        link: 'http://youtube.com',
        key: 'CAT01'
      },
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/470x249',
        categoria: 'Categoria 03',
        link: 'http://youtube.com',
        key: 'CAT02'
      }
    ],

    contenidosTres: [
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/670x551',
        categoria: 'Categoria 01',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/30/000000/FFFFFF',
        descripcion: 'Descripción de producto',
        linkSku: 'https://www.myapp.cl/myapp-homy/product/332771X',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU06'
      }
    ],

    contenidosTresRow: [
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/470x249',
        categoria: 'Categoria 02',
        link: 'http://youtube.com',
        key: 'CAT03'
      },
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/470x249',
        categoria: 'Categoria 03',
        link: 'http://youtube.com',
        key: 'CAT04'
      }
    ],

    contenidoCuatro: [
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/370x370',
        link: 'http://altavista.com',
        texto: 'Texto para link',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FFC600/FFFFFF?text=Icono',
        key: 'CAT05'
      },
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/370x370',
        link: 'http://altavista.com',
        texto: 'Texto para link',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FFC600/FFFFFF?text=Icono',
        key: 'CAT06'
      },
      {
        imagenBanner: 'http://via.placeholder.com/370x370',
        link: 'http://altavista.com',
        texto: 'Texto para link',
        icono: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FFC600/FFFFFF?text=Icono',
        key: 'CAT07'
      }
    ],

    productosContenidoCinco: [
      {
        imagenSKU: 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x200',
        linkSKU: 'http://altavista.com',
        decripcionSKU: 'Texto producto aquí',
        iconoPromo: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FFC600/FFFFFF?text=Icono',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU07'
      },
      {
        imagenSKU: 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x200',
        linkSKU: 'http://altavista.com',
        decripcionSKU: 'Texto producto aquí',
        iconoPromo: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FFC600/FFFFFF?text=Icono',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU08'
      },
      {
        imagenSKU: 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x200',
        linkSKU: 'http://altavista.com',
        decripcionSKU: 'Texto producto aquí',
        iconoPromo: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FFC600/FFFFFF?text=Icono',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU09'
      },
      {
        imagenSKU: 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x200',
        linkSKU: 'http://altavista.com',
        decripcionSKU: 'Texto producto aquí',
        iconoPromo: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FFC600/FFFFFF?text=Icono',
        precioNormal: 999999,
        precioAntes: 999999,
        key: 'SKU10'
      }
    ],

    inspiracion: [
      {
        BannerImg: 'http://via.placeholder.com/950x400',
        BannerImgMob: 'http://via.placeholder.com/400x400',
        Bloque: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100',
        BloqueDisplay: 'bloqueInspiracionContLB',
        Link: 'http://amazon.com',
        Boton: 'Ver LookBook',
        Title: 'Look Book',
        Margen: 'aLaIzquierda',
        Descripcion: 'Lorem ipsum de Look Book',
        key: 'CONTENIDO01'
      },
      {
        BannerImg: 'http://via.placeholder.com/950x400',
        BannerImgMob: 'http://via.placeholder.com/400x400',
        Bloque: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100',
        BloqueDisplay: 'bloqueInspiracionContLN',
        Link: 'http://amazon.com',
        Boton: 'Ir a lo Nuevo',
        Title: 'Lo Nuevo',
        Margen: 'aLaDerecha',
        Descripcion: 'Lorem ipsum de Lo Nuevo',
        key: 'CONTENIDO02'
      },
      {
        BannerImg: 'http://via.placeholder.com/950x400',
        BannerImgMob: 'http://via.placeholder.com/400x400',
        Bloque: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100',
        BloqueDisplay: 'bloqueInspiracionContLB',
        Link: 'http://amazon.com',
        Boton: 'Ver Todo',
        Title: 'Diseño Nacional',
        Margen: 'aLaIzquierda',
        Descripcion: 'Lorem ipsum de Diseño Nacional',
        key: 'CONTENIDO03'
      }
    ],

    blogContent: [
      {
        bannerBlog: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x250',
        titleBlog: 'Entrada de blog 01',
        parrafoBlog: 'Irure incididunt eiusmod aliqua laboris occaecat veniam sunt reprehenderit velit velit nostrud. Culpa enim proident elit sit voluptate aute adipisicing nostrud eiusmod voluptate non excepteur tempor. Consequat id deserunt ipsum mollit sint ex proident officia qui culpa irure enim Lorem. Enim elit laboris culpa esse adipisicing ullamco nulla aute occaecat nisi sunt. Cupidatat tempor aliqua ullamco qui cupidatat deserunt irure tempor reprehenderit officia Lorem. Esse laborum magna aliqua in amet dolor.',
        linkBlog: 'http://google.com',
        dateBlog: '01 de octubre del 2018',
        topico: 'Decomuro',
        key: 'BLOG01'
      },
      {
        bannerBlog: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x250',
        titleBlog: 'Entrada de blog 02',
        parrafoBlog: 'Irure incididunt eiusmod aliqua laboris occaecat veniam sunt reprehenderit velit velit nostrud. Culpa enim proident elit sit voluptate aute adipisicing nostrud eiusmod voluptate non excepteur tempor. Consequat id deserunt ipsum mollit sint ex proident officia qui culpa irure enim Lorem. Enim elit laboris culpa esse adipisicing ullamco nulla aute occaecat nisi sunt. Cupidatat tempor aliqua ullamco qui cupidatat deserunt irure tempor reprehenderit officia Lorem. Esse laborum magna aliqua in amet dolor.',
        linkBlog: 'http://google.com',
        dateBlog: '02 de octubre del 2018',
        topico: 'Adornos de Baños',
        key: 'BLOG02'
      },
      {
        bannerBlog: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x250',
        titleBlog: 'Entrada de blog 03',
        parrafoBlog: 'Irure incididunt eiusmod aliqua laboris occaecat veniam sunt reprehenderit velit velit nostrud. Culpa enim proident elit sit voluptate aute adipisicing nostrud eiusmod voluptate non excepteur tempor. Consequat id deserunt ipsum mollit sint ex proident officia qui culpa irure enim Lorem. Enim elit laboris culpa esse adipisicing ullamco nulla aute occaecat nisi sunt. Cupidatat tempor aliqua ullamco qui cupidatat deserunt irure tempor reprehenderit officia Lorem. Esse laborum magna aliqua in amet dolor.',
        linkBlog: 'http://google.com',
        dateBlog: '03 de octubre del 2018',
        topico: 'Escritorio y Oficina',
        key: 'BLOG03'
      }

    ]

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="tituloCalipso marginAuto">
            {this.state.titulos.map(titulos =>
              <ContenidoUnoTitulo
                tituloUno={titulos.tituloUno}
                key={titulos.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="blockCatPrice">
            {this.state.contenidosUno.map(contenido =>
              <ContenidoUno
                imagen={contenido.imagenBanner}
                categoria={contenido.categoria}
                link={contenido.linkCat}
                icono={contenido.icono}
                descripcion={contenido.descripcion}
                normal={contenido.precioNormal}
                antes={contenido.precioAntes}
                key={contenido.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="tituloCalipso marginAuto">
            {this.state.titulos.map(titulos =>
              <ContenidoDosTitulo
                tituloDos={titulos.tituloDos}
                key={titulos.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="blockCatPrice">
            {this.state.contenidosDos.map(contenido =>
              <ContenidoDos
                imagen={contenido.imagenBanner}
                categoria={contenido.categoria}
                icono={contenido.icono}
                link={contenido.linkSku}
                descripcion={contenido.descripcion}
                normal={contenido.precioNormal}
                antes={contenido.precioAntes}
                key={contenido.key} />
            )}
            <div>
              {this.state.contenidosDosRow.map(contenido =>
                <ContenidoDosRow
                  imagen={contenido.imagenBanner}
                  categoria={contenido.categoria}
                  ancla={contenido.link}
                  key={contenido.key}
                />)}
              <div>
                {this.state.botonesLink.map(botonesLink =>
                  <BotonesLinkUno
                    boton={botonesLink.botonUno}
                    key={botonesLink.key}
                  />)}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="tituloCalipso marginAuto">
            {this.state.titulos.map(titulos =>
              <ContenidoTresTitulo
                tituloTres={titulos.tituloTres}
                key={titulos.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="blockCatPrice">
            <div>
              {this.state.contenidosTresRow.map(contenido =>
                <ContenidoTresRow
                  imagen={contenido.imagenBanner}
                  categoria={contenido.categoria}
                  ancla={contenido.link}
                  key={contenido.key}
                />)}
              <div>
                {this.state.botonesLink.map(botonesLink =>
                  <BotonesLinkDos
                    boton={botonesLink.botonDos}
                    key={botonesLink.key}
                  />)}
              </div>
            </div>
            {this.state.contenidosTres.map(contenido =>
              <ContenidoTres
                imagen={contenido.imagenBanner}
                categoria={contenido.categoria}
                icono={contenido.icono}
                link={contenido.linkSku}
                descripcion={contenido.descripcion}
                normal={contenido.precioNormal}
                antes={contenido.precioAntes}
                key={contenido.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="tituloCalipso marginAuto">
            {this.state.titulos.map(titulos =>
              <ContenidoCuatroTitulo
                tituloCuatro={titulos.tituloCuatro}
                key={titulos.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="blockCatPrice">
            {this.state.contenidoCuatro.map(bloques =>
              <ContenidoCuatroBloques
                bloquesContentImg={bloques.imagenBanner}
                bloquesContentLink={bloques.link}
                bloquesContentTexto={bloques.texto}
                bloquesContentIcono={bloques.icono}
                key={bloques.key}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="tituloCalipso marginAuto">
            {this.state.titulos.map(titulos =>
              <ContenidoCincoTitulo
                tituloCinco={titulos.tituloCinco}
                key={titulos.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="containerHomyCarrusel">
          <Slider {...settings}>
            {this.state.productosContenidoCinco.map(contenido =>
              <ProductosDestacados
                imagen={contenido.imagenSKU}
                link={contenido.linkSKU}
                descripcion={contenido.decripcionSKU}
                normal={contenido.precioNormal}
                antes={contenido.precioAntes}
                icono={contenido.iconoPromo}
                key={contenido.key} />
            )}
          </Slider>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="tituloCalipso marginAuto">
            {this.state.titulos.map(titulos =>
              <ContenidoSeisTitulo
                tituloSeis={titulos.tituloSeis}
                key={titulos.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <div className="containerInspiracion">
            {this.state.inspiracion.map(contenido =>
              <Inspiracion
                banner={contenido.BannerImg}
                bannerMob={contenido.BannerImgMob}
                descripcion={contenido.Descripcion}
                box={contenido.Bloque}
                boton={contenido.Boton}
                link={contenido.Link}
                title={contenido.Title.split(' ')}
                margen={contenido.Margen}
                boxdisplay={contenido.BloqueDisplay}
                key={contenido.key}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="tituloCalipso marginAuto">
            {this.state.titulos.map(titulos =>
              <ContenidoSieteTitulo
                tituloSiete={titulos.tituloSiete}
                key={titulos.key} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="blockCatPrice">
            {this.state.blogContent.map(item =>
              <ThirdContent
                banner={item.bannerBlog}
                title={item.titleBlog}
                preview={item.parrafoBlog}
                link={item.linkBlog}
                date={item.dateBlog}
                topic={item.topico}
                key={item.key}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please explain which data fail to render and which component. In your code there are many components. So it's really difficult to look into all your code and understand what is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question, thanks for the feedback...

Comment: This ProductosDestacados code looks fine. Isn't that rendering?

Comment: Yes it's fine, but the data is static i would like to use the data from Json... So I can the static data from state...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this simplified example we use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to call the API when the component mounts. While the data is being fetched from the API we show a **Loading Products...** message.

When the request is complete we store the data in `state.products`. Once the state change is detected the component will re-render and display the `ProductosDestacados` component where `state.products` is being passed as a `prop`. In `ProductosDestacados` you can access this data through `props.products`.

This should help you get the basic idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWebServiceResponse();
    }
    getWebServiceResponse = () => {
        axios(getProductDetailAPI(currentList, storeId))
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(newData => {
            // store response in state
            this.setState({products: newData.products});
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { products } = this.state;
        if (products.length) {
            return <ProductosDestacados products={products}/>;
        }
        else return (
            <div>Loading Products...</div>
        );
    }
}
```

> `componentWillMount()` is considered legacy and you should avoid using it in new code.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle